# Azure SQL: get all values of JSON of a column

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, json-query, json-value

I have simplified my problem for the sake of this question, I am trying to get all the `ReferenceId` and `Options` values of the JSON using SQL but I am getting `NULL`. Can someone help me with this?

```
DECLARE @jsonInfo VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @jsonInfo='{
"Resources": [
    {
        "Id": "fa611f1a-554b-4630-b0c6-4ec846452c8c",
        "Options": [
            "340e67c6-7b6f-4b15-82ad-d0198d44fc67",
            "3c743e42-c669-41f6-a807-4726fac39e0b"
        ]
    
    },
    {
        "Id": "360ed9dd-44bb-4758-abb8-dc914e13b443",
        "Options": [
            "3b4165d1-af46-486b-b9b0-8cc924d42be6"
        ]
    
    }
],
"References": [
    {
        "ReferenceId": "ea2f6534-d5f5-4028-b285-ad85b3c45f10"
    },
    {
        "ReferenceId": "f8fb63a0-f60b-4c77-a9f0-22ffdb3c07ac"
    },
    {
        "ReferenceId": "d8ce4f46-0417-4972-b098-83219b6c7a4f"
    
    }
]
}';

SELECT JSON_VALUE(@jsonInfo, '$.References.ReferenceId')
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@jsonInfo, '$.Resources.Options')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a **single** value using this approach, something like this:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@jsonInfo, '$.References[0].ReferenceId')
```

But if you want the whole list of values from the `References` (or `Resources`) array, you need to use `OPENJSON` and a defined "output shape" like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonInfo, N'$.References')
WITH (ReferenceId VARCHAR(50) '$.ReferenceId')
```

Now you should get:

```
ReferenceId
------------------------------------
ea2f6534-d5f5-4028-b285-ad85b3c45f10
f8fb63a0-f60b-4c77-a9f0-22ffdb3c07ac
d8ce4f46-0417-4972-b098-83219b6c7a4f
```

Comment: in my usecase I have the JSON data is on links column of Documents table so I tried using it in my sql query as `SELECT OPENJSON(links, N'$.References') from [Documents]` but am getting 'OPENJSON' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @RanPaul: what **version** of SQL Server are you running? Run `SELECT @@VERSION` to find out

Comment: Am using Azure data studio and the version is `Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8  Jul 23 2021 13:14:19  Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation`